# Como faço para receber o valor de Variáveis Separadamente do PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Esse é o codigo do Ajax

```
$('#FormEs').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "VerificarPerson.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data: {
            'metodo': $('#metodo').val(),
            'idp': $('#idp').val(),
            'personName': $('#personName').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data); // <------------------------------------------------

    });

});
```

e Esse é o PHP

```
<?php
    if(strcasecmp('Teste', $_POST['metodo']) == 0){
        $html1 = $_POST['personName'];
        $html2 = $_POST['personName2'];
        echo $html1; /

  }
?>
```

Bom eu queria  mostrar as duas variaveis tipo `alert('html1')` e depois `alert('html2')` tipo isso alguém sabe como?

Comment: Sinceramente, recorri ao manual do PHP para ver o que era esse `strcasecmp()`, mas sua questão é simples. :P

Comment: Eu fico impressionado, as pessoas negativam sem ao menos tentar ajudar ou pelo menos criticar em que você está errando.

Comment: pois é amigo me cadastrei um dia desse pq soube que aqui no Stackoverflow eu poderia pedir ajuda mais pelo visto algumas pessoas não entendem isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o JSON, ele é seu amigo.

> JavaScript:

No Javascript/JQuery irá precisar declarar algumas coisas, primeiramente o `dataType` e então criar um loop para ler todos os dados do `JSON`.

```
$.ajax({
//...
dataType: "json",
//...
}).done(function(data){

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    alert(data[i]);
}

});
```

> PHP:

O PHP também precisa sair em JSON, para isso utilize o `json_encode()`, mas torne o que deseja em uma `array()`, dessa forma terá mais de um dado.

```
<?php

        $html[] = $_POST['personName'];
        $html[] = $_POST['personName2'];
        // Este [] irá tornar o html em uma array
        // Será: array('personName', 'personName2');

        echo json_encode($html);
        // Irá sair: ["personName","personName2"]
        // Que será lido pelo data[i] no Javascript

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, foi do jeito que eu queria xD